# Agregar valores a una tabla si es padre o si es hijo

Tags: php

tengo una tabla en la base de datos en donde el rut esta asociado a lineas telefónicas. en el registro para ingresar, debo validar el rut del registro con el rut de la base de datos y el número telefónico del registro con uno de los números asociados al rut de la base de datos si estos dos son verdaderos el usuario es padre ¿como puedo determinar esta condición y que me inserte los valores si es padre en la tabla de los padres y si es hijo en la de los hijos pero si es hijo que este asociado al padre?

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Las preguntas sin código no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que aprendas como realizar una pregunta y evitar que te la cierren.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

    $conexion = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$bd);
    // variables que recibes
    $ruc = $_POST['ruc'];
    $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];

    //asumo que la tabla donde guardas los datos se llama datos

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM datos WHERE ruc = '$ruc' AND telefono = '$telefono';";
    $resul = $conexion->query($sql);
    $row_cnt = $resul->num_rows;   // cuento si me trajo algun registro
    if($row_cnt > 0) // si almenos tiene un registro
    {
       $sql = "INSERT INTO padre (ruc, telefono) VALUES ('$ruc', '$telefono');";
       $conexion->query($sql);

    }else{
         $sql = "INSERT INTO hijo (ruc, telefono) VALUES ('$ruc', '$telefono');";
       $conexion->query($sql);

    }


?>
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a la comunidad. Es maravilloso que quieras aportar pero evitamos responder a preguntas de baja calidad ya que pueden terminar cerradas. En su lugar, orientamos al OP para que se más específico en su pregunta y luego procedemos a responder. Te invito a hacer [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que sepas de lo que hablo.